# document.cookie only stores first key-value pair?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to store a pretty simple string in the `document.cookie` but it seems to only store the first key-value pair every time:

```js
function setCookieDetails(persistence, version) {
    let cookieString = 'persistChangelog=' + persistence + ';changelogVersion=' + version + ';path=/';
    document.cookie = cookieString;
}
```

I don't need to store a lot of information in this cookie. It's to store some information about a changelog window. But when I store this information instead of the string looking like this:

> persistChangelog=false;changelogVersion=1;path=/

It becomes this:

> persistChangelog=false

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a lot of cookies in one time, you can use function like this to do other way can help you:

```
function setCookie(persistence , version ) {

    if (persistence) {
        document.cookie = "persistChangelog=" + persistence;
    }
    if (version) {
        document.cookie = "changelogVersion=" + version;
    }
}
```

Then call this function.